# Markdown vs. HTML in a CMS

Tags: php, html, markdown

I'm working on a fairly large CMS-like app that includes a forum, wiki pages, etc. What whould you chose between Markdown and HTML? I'm concerned about usability and the fact non-techie people will use this.

- Markdown has a very simple syntax but few users know it
- with HTML you can use a WYSIWYG editor but they are often terrible

Comment: I hate markdown. In every text editor I use, I automagically use its keyboard shortcuts, even in ones not supporting it ;)

Comment: Every html editor I've used so far sucks, if not at first, it sucks after some updates, or after some new special copy paste actions (try from indesign!) a year after setup. You'll always end up with divs and style tags you dont want or anything else you didn't expect in the first place, when setting things up. things then get complicated. Sure, you can configure things to avoid such things, and I've configured a lot, but always expect the unexpected! IMHO having some kind of enhanced markdown editor would be the win - give your users the "bold" button...and maybe even a live preview.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If usability is an issue, and the target audience is non-geeks, WYSIWYG wins over Markdown. People are used to the toolbars with formatting buttons, but Markdown is a completely unknown markup language to most people (even "markup language" is completely unknown!).

I've had to explain a Markdown-lookalike wiki syntax to non-geeks at work, and they don't love it. **When you want to write something, you want to write something, not look up weird ASCII syntax.** Try not to interrupt the users' flow.

I would find a good WYSIWYG editor, like the one in WordPress ([TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)). It works ok.

Comment: I can't agree... WYSIWG editors corrupt content (all of them), angering users far more than the requirement to learn the intuitive markdown syntax. And mediawiki syntax is not lovable, I agree.. Markdown is a completely different thing. It's obvious

Comment: I have had similar feedback: markdown is many things, but "normal" user friendly it is not. Markdown has many "hidden" conventions that a normal users will break or bump against, it is very fragile wrt misplaced whitespace f.i. WYSYWYG is the way to go for normal users, thankfully it has improved a lot.

Answer (score 24):

I vote for Markdown.

1. I picked up Markdown in maybe 5 minutes in writing my first response here. Later
   I learned more than what I picked up here, but I'd think this to be rather standard.
2. Markdown is much simpler to get good markup out of, and if you're worried about
   speed just cache the resulting output.
3. Markdown is often better, and more easily understood, in plain text than HTML is
   in a WYSIWYG editor. Also, no-script friendly.

And if you've got a user who wants an embeded object, just drop the HTML code from that Youtube video in and it'll get carried over.

Comment: Yes, I thought about caching the HTML too, and using it for viewing only.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the (very well done) stackoverflow WYSIWYG markdown editor is open source

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to use Markdown **and** a WYSIWYG editor you can use something like [WMD Editor](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pagedown/) which (I am 99% sure) is what is used here at StackOverflow.

The benefit of using something like this is that your non-tech users get their WYSIWYG editor, your techie users get their Markdown love and you get clean markup. Another added side effect is it may actually teach end users Markdown from using it (or at least in an ideal world...)

WMD Editor also has an instant preview (which you can see when writing posts on StackOverflow), which will show users how changing the Markdown changes the look of their text.

Answer (score 2):

We store XHTML in the database, validated against a restricted XHTML schema. The front-end is either a WYSIWYG editor (for the staff who know how to deal with its quirks) or a plain-text box (for the users, with automatic link detection etc.). We can convert the content back and forth, although the plain-text box loses formatting, so we do not depend on a specific UI. If we needed more than this, I would add another converter from XHTML to markdown.

Comment: +1 if you must use HTML, well-formed and restricted XHTML is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer **Markdown** with flat-file CMS, like [Grav](https://getgrav.org/) or other.

It's simpler to change styles, but not any html content. And you will take one killer feature: use **git** for web-site content. You even can create branches with "holiday" content.

Actually Markdown is simpler for non-tech people.